# says you need 50 reputation points to comment. I have one. This can't be right. How can I participate?

Tags: discussion, community

title says it all. I just find a lot of these pages which I'd like to participate in but I run into this problem

Comment: Now you have five more points.

Comment: You have to earn 50 points, by editing other's posts, asking good questions which get upvoted, or answering questions that don't need clarification through comments.

Comment: This is correct and is in place for reason, see the duplicate post

Comment: I guess my instinct rather than create a new question is to ask within one already created that's related.  But whatever.  If I just need to ask questions to comment on existing questions I guess I'll just create a new question. Thanks